# Docker in VM in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have created a VM in AWS. Assign to it Security Group with PORTS 8080-8089 Open.
Inside my VM I am running a docker of a server mapping my VM port 8081 to the Docker port 8080.
using "docker run --name mynameddocker -d -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8080 webapp"

Now, Inside my VM I can access localhost:8081 using a web browser. But the issue is trying to access it from outside VM.!!!!
My assumption that I can access it using AWS_Instatance_Public_IP:8081.

But nothing worked. I have a security rule that states open all TCP port, but still no access.
I have tried the same in Google Cloud Platform. But no progress
Any Idea ??

Comment: Does your "webapp" listen on 0.0.0.0 inside the container?

Comment: How to check for that ? I am able to view the app at localhost:8081 outside at the VM... I assume it does

Comment: can you try without ip `docker run --name mynameddocker -d -p 8081:8080 webapp`, also, have you double check the inbound port hace type HTTP, that you opened

Comment: Without the "0.0.0.0" was actually my start, it did not work. I am new at all this "learner" so pair with me. What you mean type HTTP ?

Comment: @Sami The way you check is really dependent on what is inside of the docker image.

Comment: @sami, in security groups > inbound rules > see if you hace custom tcp againts both ports

Comment: 1) What is the exact error when you try to connect? 2) Do you have `iptables` rules allowing this port?

Comment: There's quite a few settings you may need to set up in order to get Docker to work in AWS I created a Terraform that does it https://registry.terraform.io/modules/trajano/swarm-aws/docker/5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking that the first step (test your container image locally) is already covered, you just need to assure to have the ports mapped correctly and opened to make the connections to flow from outside to your container; we were able to reproduce the issue on GCP, using an ‘Ngnix’ image which by default has open the 80/tcp port and the port was menter image description hereapped using the 8081 port (as yours),

1.here the command we used:

`docker run --name nginx-new -d -p 8081:80 nginx`

Meaning that 80 is my container's port and 8081 is the port mapped on the host VM in GCP.

2. On a firewall rule we opened port 8081, that is the one opened on my host to receive connections and map these connections to the container's 80 port.
3. Basically outsider connections will go like:
   *Browser:http://host-ip:8080* >> *GCP project firewall* >> *Instance port 8081* >> *container port 80* >> _succesfull connection!

**Troubleshooting (please refer to the attached images, for a better reference)...

- Checked ports opened on my container ([container-troubleshoot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGlqe.png))
- Test through the container port and IP ([image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2bzT.png))
- Checked ports opened on my VM ([VM-ports.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT2vh.png))
- Test through the VM port using instance internal IP ([image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmMFZ.png))
- Test through the VM port using instance external IP ([image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lVhJ.png))
- Test using browser using instance external IP ([image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blRjx.png))

It will be useful to know your error message, but I would suggest you to follow the above steps to validate if used ports are mapped and opened in the container and in the VM instance.

Comment: Wow... thank very much Erick for your effort. It was accessible fine from within the instance. For some strange reason, I stopped the instance and run it again ... and it worked. I am sure it was a port issue. Erick thank you again ... now at least I know how to check the ports issue if any future issue. Thank you all.